# How to place a text above a card deck?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[what I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i5cG.png)

[what I have for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUmQW.png)

my code is:

```html
<div class="card-deck test">
    <div class="card-group mx-auto test2">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">
            <h2>Überblick</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card overviewCard text-center">
            <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex">
                <div>
                <!-- Content here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- More cards here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS classes `test`, `test2` are just to show the borders, the class `overviewHeader` to style the header and the class `overviewCard` styles the card.
How can I put my header above and at the beginning of the card deck, like it is in the first reference image.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You need to put the title in a separate container or row. With the current code, it treats it like a separate column inside a row.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flexbox property `<div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">` from bootstrap wrapping the `<h2>Überblick</h2>`.

That is what's causing it to be inline.

Take `<h2>Überblick</h2>` out of those divs. Place it on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box to achieve this.

1. Make a parent div and then make its height, 100% and width too.
2. Then set `display: flex` on it and `justify-content: center;` to align it to center.
3. Create another div to hold the cards and scale it to a width which is less than 100%. To achieve the effect. Now add `display:flex` here too and `justify-content:space-between`. Why you ask? Because `space-between` will align the cards with equal widths from each other. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content/#space-between
4. Then add divs inside the parent divs. Style the cards, add `max-width`, `height` and a subtle `box-shadow`. Arrange the colors according to your preferences. This can result in [something like this](https://s.codepen.io/weegee12/debug/mNEVRm/YvMgOnNZKyzM)

This below is the more responsive and scaled-down version. Enough to give you an idea.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 300px;
}

.card-deck {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  justify-content: center
}

.card-group {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.notification {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #3498db;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -10px;
}

.overviewHeader {
  max-width: 20%;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 17px 6px 29px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 17px 6px 29px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 1);
  box-shadow: 17px 6px 29px 0px rgba(214, 214, 214, 1);
}

.overviewHeader h2 {
font-size:15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-center {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.some-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #bdc3c7;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-deck test">
  <div class="card-group mx-auto test2">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">
      <div class="notification"></div>
      <div class="some-image">
      </div>
      <h2>Überblick</h2>

      <div class="card overviewCard text-center">
        <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex">
          <div>
            Some Content;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">
      <div class="some-image">
      </div>
      <h2>Überblick</h2>

      <div class="card overviewCard text-center">
        <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex">
          <div class="text-center">
            Some Content;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">
      <div class="some-image">
      </div>
      <h2>Überblick</h2>

      <div class="card overviewCard text-center">
        <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex">
          <div>
            Some Content;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start overviewHeader">
      <div class="some-image">
      </div>
      <h2>Überblick</h2>

      <div class="card overviewCard text-center">
        <div class="card-body align-items-center d-flex">
          <div>
            Some Content;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```